# Starting different plugins in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

I have a base abstract class. There are several classes which extend from this class. These could be specified as different plugins. Then there is a main class which starts these plugins using reflection. I need to start each plugin in a separate thread. Below are the lines which start the plugins using reflection.

```
Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(className);
if (className.endsWith(currentPlugin.messageListner)) {
    // The MessageListner class found ...
    TestMessageListener messageListner = null;
    messageListner = (TestMessageListener) c.getConstructor(MessageBus.class, String.class)
            .newInstance(messageBus, currentPlugin.initParam);
    if (messageListner.start() == false) {
        currentPlugin.loadStatus = "failed";
        currentPlugin.errorCode = "Plugin start failed.";
    } else {
        currentPlugin.loadStatus = "success";
        currentPlugin.errorCode = "";
    }
    break;
}
```

So I thought of wrapping the above code segment into a thread as it will be executed for each plugin(It is inside a while loop). Are there any other ways in which I could do this? Below is the structure of my base class.

```
public abstract class TestMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    protected String initParam;

    protected int instanceId;

    public TestMessageListener(MessageBus messageBus, String initParam) {
        if (messageBus == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.messageBus = messageBus;
        this.initParam = initParam;
        String[] params = initParam.split(",");
        if ((params.length >= 1) && !params[0].isEmpty()) {
            // assign the first parameter as the instanceId
            instanceId = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
        }
    }
    public abstract boolean start();
}
```

Comment: what code you need to be executed in separate thread.Is it the start method of each messagelistner?

Comment: Yes, loading the constructor through reflection and calling the start method. Those two are the lines I need to call in a separate thread for each plugin.

Comment: why you put `break;` after loading single class? You only require single class/plugin to be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 if (className.endsWith(currentPlugin.messageListner)) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //your thread code
                 TestMessageListener messageListner = null;
                    messageListner = (TestMessageListener) c.getConstructor(MessageBus.class, String.class)
                            .newInstance(messageBus, currentPlugin.initParam);
                    if (messageListner.start() == false) {
                        currentPlugin.loadStatus = "failed";
                        currentPlugin.errorCode = "Plugin start failed.";
                    } else {
                        currentPlugin.loadStatus = "success";
                        currentPlugin.errorCode = "";
                    }

            }
        }).start();//starting the thread
}
```

Comment: So this will make the execution of all methods in all the plugins run in different threads right? I mean a thread per plugin?

Comment: correct. You have only start method in plugin . right?

Comment: After starting the plugin, I do call other methods in them. Won't they also work in the thread in which their object got created?

Comment: I don't understand your issue fully, anyhow each thread will end up after executing its `run()` method. I f you want to execute anything more you should do within its `run()` method.

Comment: What this run method does is that it allows the plugins to subscribe to certain methods. When events related to the subscribed methods are fired there are certain callback methods that should be executed. So how can I make these callbacks also to execute in the same thread as the 'start' method?

Comment: I think your reqirement is not demanding the asked multithreading instead it is a publish -subscribe system you want(observer pattern).Let me understand - you have a set of plugins(listeners/observers) that listening for certain events/messages and when such events occured these plugins get notified and you need to execute some actions or callbacks. is it true?

Comment: Exactly! So I want all these methods to get executed from different threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98646/discussion-between-tom-sebastian-and-mayooran).